# Finding the 3rd vetices location on the coordinate system

Tags: c++, math, determinants

So, here is the problem.
I am given the lengths of 3 sides of a triangle.
The program calculates the area of the given triangle using determinates.
I assume that one vertex of the triangle is in the (0,0) point and the 2nd one is in the (c,0), where c is the length of the longest side. So what would be the easiest way to get the 3rd vertices coordinates.
I tried cosine theorem to get the line equation the side is going through, but it is a bit off
I have the determination solver program if you need it down here:

```
    float det(int n, float mat[3][3])
{
int d=0;
int c, subi, i, j, subj;
float submat[3][3];  
if(n == 2) {
            return( (mat[0][0] * mat[1][1]) - (mat[1][0] * mat[0][1]));
            }
else{  
    for(c = 0; c < n; c++){  
            subi = 0;  
            for(i = 1; i < n; i++){  
                subj = 0;
                for(j = 0; j < n; j++){    
                    if (j == c){
                        continue;
                    }
                    submat[subi][subj] = mat[i][j];
                    subj++;
                }
                subi++;
            }
        d = d + (pow(-1 ,c) * mat[0][c] * det(n - 1 ,submat));
        }
    }
    return d;

}
```

.
.
.

```
ans=det.det(3,coords)*0.5;
```

Example picture of the triangle constructed in GeoGebra:

[image: img]

Comment: The question is not clear. Given the length of all sides, and the position of 2 vertices, there are multiple triangles that could be drawn. Do you know *which* sides correspond to *which* vertices?

Comment: Why not use [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)? `Area = sqrt(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c))` with `s = (a+b+c)/2`

Comment: simply solve the intersection point of 2 cast circles on your image... so system of 2 quadratic equations .. no determinants areas or whatever is needed.